# Highchart Display Marker on Top Position

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to display marker on top position of **area spline** chart. But marker is not connected with chart line and move away. when Chart line stopped then it connected with marker.

```
I want marker connected with graph line.
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/8aevhxp2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the animation of point update:

```
series.data[series.data.length - 1].update({
    marker: {
        enabled: true
    }
}, true, false)
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5nm6y01q/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update